# How to get Joomla login form url for redirection

Tags: joomla

I have custom component. For now everyone can access the page with this component. I want to redirect user to login page if he is not loged in. How to get login page url?

In my components view I write:

```
if($user->id != 0) {
    ..
}
else {
    $link = JRoute::_(???????);
    $this->setRedirect($link);  
}
```

Another question - is it ok to put into view or should I put it somwhere else?
I am using Joomla 2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ,

In that component view you have to restrict only for logged in users then,

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id != 0){

 // show your view
}
else{

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->redirect('index.php?option=com_users&view=login');
}
```

You can use this code any where inside view.html.php,layouts etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify, so I'm presuming Joomla 2.5.x.

In you view class seems to be the *standard* place... e.g. `com_content` checks in it's `article/view.html.php` file, with the following:

```
// Check the view access to the article (the model has already computed the values).
if ($item->params->get('access-view') != true && (($item->params->get('show_noauth') != true &&  $user->get('guest') ))) {
    JError::raiseWarning(403, JText::_('JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR'));

    return;
}
```

As you can see, `com_content` doesn't redirect the user, it simply raises a blocking warning message.

`com_users` can be called with a `redirect` parameter that contain the URL you want the user sent to after they login. The parameter should be `base64` encoded and escaped with `urlendcode`. You can read about the [redirect after login](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_redirect_users_after_a_successful_login?) mechanism on [docs.joomla.org](http://docs.joomla.org/).

To achieve a redirect to the login and then return to the original request after a successful login you can use something similar to this in your `else` block:

```
// Redirect to login
$uri        = JFactory::getURI();
$return     = $uri->toString();

$url  = 'index.php?option=com_users&amp;view=login&amp;return=' . urlencode(base64_encode($return));

$jAp->redirect($url, JText::_('Message_about_this_view_requiring_login'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ideally placed in the controller: but you could do much the same in the view.

first, encode your return link:

```
$link = base64_encode(JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=someview&tmpl=somelayout", false));
```

then, build the route to the login page:

```
$rlink = JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=$link", false);
$msg = JText::_("COM_YOURCOMPONENT_LOGIN_TO_ACCESS");
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect($rlink, $msg);
```