# Adding restriction to joomla components to logged out user

Tags: joomla2.5

I have developed a component in Joomla and i want this component to be used by only registered user. If a non-registered user trying to access the url, it should redirect to login page. How this can be done in Joomla 2.5? Please Help

Comment: This is a very similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/17638877/1983389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the answer in the link that @Neil Robertson suggested or you can simply set the access level to registered when you create the menu item for your component.